# How to place the checkBox In between rows of tableview

Tags: iphone

My Problem is I want to place the checkbox in between the rows of the tableview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HI... There is nothing like check box friend and for showing that you have to use custom cell and use imageview in it that showing that check box.. you have to change the image when user click on it with tick image and if again clcik on the same hen it change with cross or disappear...

```
if( check == 0 )
{       
    UIButton *selectedButton = (UIButton *)sender;

    if (editCount%2 == 0) {

        [(UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:160] setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"YOUR TICK IMAGE",[selectedButton tag]] ofType:@"png"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

}   else {

```
        [(UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:160] setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"YOUR CROSS IMAGE",[selectedButton tag]] ofType:@"png"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];            

    editCount++;

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

As you know that there is no check box's available in SDK.I had used two images as it looks like checkBox. One with Checked and other with unchecked.

set these images to button and place it on the cell. you can add a flag to set the type.

For reference try this [link](http://iphonesdevsdk.blogspot.com/2011/04/custom-tableview.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can call a custom UITableViewCell that contains the wanted checkbox.

Say you have another Custom Cell that displays the info..

In your UITableViewController when you call the custom view, you can add a flag to set the type of cell you need to do so you can have an array like this:

{{data, 0}, {check,1}, {data,0}}

Where the 0 stands for the default Custom Cell and 1 for the checkboxed one,

then in UITableViewController you look at the flag and do as needed.